# Laravel 5.2 QueryException in Connection.php line 669

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, relation

i'm developing an API but when I create the relations (Many to Many) and want to show in the `index` function I'm getting an error `QueryException in Connection.php line 669` The error says:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CTL_Tags.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `CTL_Tags`.*, `CTL_Resource_has_Tags`.`idResource` as `pivot_idResource`, `CTL_Resource_has_Tags`.`idTag` as `pivot_idTag` from `CTL_Tags` inner join `CTL_Resource_has_Tags` on `CTL_Tags`.`id` = `CTL_Resource_has_Tags`.`idTag` where `CTL_Resource_has_Tags`.`idResource` is null)
```

I believe my error is in my model because it's looking for `id` in `CTL_Tags` table when my id name in that table is `idTag`.

This is my CTL_Resource model

```
<?php

namespace Knotion;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CTL_Resource extends Model  {
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = "CTL_Resource";

    protected $hidden = [
      'coachVisibility', 'thumbnail', 'tags', 'relatedTo',
      'studentVisibility', 'isHTML','studentIndex', 'coachIndex',
      'isURL', 'source', 'path', 'status', 'updateTime', 'isfolder',
      'parentResource', 'idModifierUser'
    ];

    protected $fillable = ['idResourceType','productionKey', 'tags', 'idCreatorUser', 'idModifierUser', 'idCreationCountry', 'title', 'description', 'URL', 'fileName', 'extension', 'quicktag', 'minimumAge', 'maximumAge', 'productionKey'];

    public function creatorUser() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\OPR_User', 'idCreatorUser');
    }
    public function creationCountry() {
      return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\CTL_Country', 'idCreationCountry');
    }
    public function resourceType()  {
      return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\CTL_ResourceType', 'idResourceType');
    }
    public function quickTags() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Knotion\CTL_QuickTag', 'CTL_Resource_has_QuickTags', 'idResource', 'idQuickTag');
    }
    public function tags() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Knotion\CTL_Tag','CTL_Resource_has_Tags', 'idResource', 'idTag');
    }
    public function relatedTo() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Knotion\CTL_RelatedTo', 'CTL_Resource_has_RelatedTo', 'idResource', 'idRelatedTo');
    }

}
```

and I just will show you the code of one of the relations

```
<?php

namespace Knotion;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CTL_QuickTag extends Model  {
    protected $table = "CTL_QuickTags";
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    protected $hidden = ['status', 'createTime', 'updateTime'];

    public function resources() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Knotion\CTL_Resource', 'CTL_Resource_has_QuickTags', 'idResource', 'idQuickTag');
    }
}
```

and this is my Controller

```
<?php

namespace Knotion\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Knotion\Http\Requests;
use Knotion\Http\Requests\ResourcesRequest;

use Knotion\CTL_Resource;
use Knotion\CTL_Tag;
use Knotion\CTL_QuickTag;
use Knotion\CTL_RelatedTo;
use Knotion\CTL_ResourceType;


class ResourcesController extends Controller  {

    public function index(Request $request)    {

        $resources = CTL_Resource::paginate(10);

        $resources->each(function($resources) {
          $resources->tags;
          $resources->quickTags;
          $resources->relatedTo;
        });

        return response()->json(
          $resources
      );
```

I'll be so grateful who anyone can help me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define

```
$primaryKey
```

in your model , with the correct column name

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#defining-models

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked! The error has gone, but I can't see the relations, it appears an empty array, but I think thats another problem. Thank you so much. :)